# Laravel fortify endpoint `user/password` change middleware to sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum, laravel-fortify

Fortify already has a route for changing password of a user

```
 PUT             api/user/password .. user-password.update › Laravel\Fortify › PasswordController@update
                  ⇂ api
                  ⇂ App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:web
```

I am using sanctum to authenticate the user. I tried changing the fortify config middleware to

```
'middleware' => ['api', 'auth:sanctum'],
```

Now when I try to view the route list with verbose I got

```
  PUT             api/user/password .. user-password.update › Laravel\Fortify › PasswordController@update
                  ⇂ api
                  ⇂ App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:sanctum
                  ⇂ App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate:web
```

But when I hit the endpoint using PUT request `api/user/password` I get `"message": "Unauthenticated."` status even I got the correct bearer token I just generated.

Can someone tell me what needs to be done or what I did wrong? Thanks in advance.